# What is the meaning of a variable surrounded by two at symbols (@) in bash?

Tags: bash

I came across this line in a bash script:

`application=@applicationName@`

Then I later see `application` being used as a variable (e.g. `${application}`). But I have no idea what the two "at symbols" (@) are doing or the meaning of this syntax. I have never seen it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Bash is concerned, this is just a string like any other, as if you did:

```sh
application="@applicationName@"
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not part of `bash`. The file is intended to be proprocessed by some other program (replacing `@applicationName@` with an actual name somewhere else) before being executed by `bash`.